# Magento 2: Is it possible to add a Price attribute to Customer entity?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, customer-attribute

I'm trying to add a custom field called **minimum order amount** to the Customer entity.

The input field should be appropriate for dollar amounts, so the best option I found is **price**.

Here is my code:

```
        // minimum order
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            'customer',
            'minimum_order_amount',
            [                                                                                                                                                   
                'type' => 'decimal',                                                                                                                            
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price',
                'label' => 'Minimum order amount',
                'input' => 'price',
                'visible' => true,                                                                                                                              
                'required' => false,
                'system' => false,
                'position' => 152,
            ]
        );
        $a = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'minimum_order_amount');
        $a->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']
        );
        $a->save();
```

There are no errors when I run `magento setup:upgrade`, but the field does not appear in the admin area.

If I use **text** instead of **price**, then the field shows up.  But it shows up with 4 decimal places and no validation.  For example entering **$500** into the field will result in saving '0' to the database.

Is there a way to use a price attribute attached to the Customer entity?  Or is there an alternative to validating this field as a dollar amount?

Comment: Try  adding 500 only (without $ sign)..

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal: sure I know that.  But my client will probably make this mistake, that's why I'd like to have this field validated as a dollar amount.